# Containing two imageView in the same row in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-imageview, expandablelistview

I have a expandable listView, and I wanna introduce four imageView in child row and each one have their own functionality when you click it. Is it possible? Now when I click anyone, the app always does the last functionality.
Where do I find an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes you can create your own Adapter for your listview and have several clickable elements in there. 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-custom-adapter-with-imageview.html

and then just:

```
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

in your adapter and then do whatever you want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from here :

http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-create-custom-expandablelistview.html

Comment: But in this examples there aren't any example with two imagenView with onClick own

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to make your own `Adapter` and then you can do basically anything you want with your `expandableListView`. Some of the examples are here [survivingwithandroid.com](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html), [androidhive.com](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and here is a youtube video [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m1aP-C5wi0).

Comment: But in this examples there aren't any example with two imagenView with onClick own

Comment: That's no different, coding is same as of 1 imageView.

Answer (score 0):

I got this inside of; public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

```
        ImageView clock = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clock);
        clock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, TimeTableActivity.class );
                    mContext.startActivity(i);

        });


        ImageView place = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        place.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setMessage("map?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

and I always see map's message, even if I click clock image.

Thanks again